# Specify Z-order of lines

Tags: ios-charts

I plot an unknown number of series. For sake of explanation, assume that there are three; `a`, `b` and `c`.

This leads the issue with the first serie `a` to be "hidden" behind the other series. This is most noticeable when then each have different colors assigned. I could plot them in the reverse order (beginning with `c`), but then the legend would be in reverse as well.

Is there a way to specify that `a` should be on top of `b` and `b` on top of `c`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly chart you are using. But for example for `LineChartView` you can define your custom renderer as a descendant of  `LineChartRenderer` class and override some functions e.g. `drawData`. In fact, you can just copy this function to your class and change only the drawing order of data sets.

```
class MyCustomRenderer: LineChartRenderer {

    // I define my custom initializer for convenience
    init(for chart: LineChartView) {
        super.init(dataProvider: chart, animator: chart.chartAnimator, viewPortHandler: chart.viewPortHandler)
    }

    init(view: LineChartView) {
        super.init(dataProvider: view, animator: view.chartAnimator, viewPortHandler: view.viewPortHandler)
    }

    override func drawData(context: CGContext)
    {
        guard let lineData = dataProvider?.lineData else { return }

        // Here you can change the drawing order !
        for i in 0 ..< lineData.dataSetCount  
        {
            guard let set = lineData.getDataSetByIndex(i) else { continue }

            if set.isVisible
            {
                if !(set is ILineChartDataSet)
                {
                    fatalError("Datasets for LineChartRenderer must conform to ILineChartDataSet")
                }

                drawDataSet(context: context, dataSet: set as! ILineChartDataSet)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And setup you render for your chart using `renderer` property.

```
myLineChartView.renderer = MyCustomRenderer(for: myLineChartView)
```